# Angular (v12) detect browser triggered navigation to send Google analytics call

Tags: angular, google-analytics, angular-router, angular12

Having 'ga' call in `app.component.ts` in router event works only when we navigate from the app, if you enter a path in the browser search bar directly the event is not triggered.

app.component.ts

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.router.events.subscribe((event: any) => {
      if(event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        ga('set', 'page', event.urlAfterRedirects);
        ga('send', 'pageview');
      }
    })
  }
```

Navigating directly to a path from browser like `https://example.com/some-path` does not trigger the above event.

Having 'ga' call in `ngOnInit()` in every route is a solution but its redundant. Any effective solution for this?

And also having the above ga code in `ngOnInit()` instead of `ngAfterViewInit()` also does not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case if someone is having the same problem, like the question says in local when you do `ng s` GA does not work on browser triggered navigation, but in the production server, since we configure nginx/apache to serve angular app we redirect 404 pages to root of the app and from there angular handles redirections to specified route or a 404 page, this is treated as in app navigation and GA works.

nginx config:

`try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;`